# Tricoastal, quadricoastal, and hexacoastal countries

Tags: geometry, geography

Let’s define a distinct coastline as a coastline you can theoretically walk completely without going through the territory of another country. For example, apart from islands, Mexico has two coastlines: one on the Pacific, and one on the Gulf of Mexico. On its main island, Ireland only has one, because even though it’s interrupted by Northern Ireland, you can still walk all the way from Drumskellan to Omeath without going through the U.K., by taking the long way around. Let’s count coastlines on oceans and major saltwater seas (e.g. the Mediterranean and the Black Sea), but not coastlines on inland seas (e.g. the Caspian and the Dead Sea).

By my count, there are 29 countries with multiple distinct coastlines on the same landmass, and most of them only have two.

1. Can you name the four countries in the world that have exactly three distinct coastlines on one landmass?
2. Can you name the three countries in the world that have exactly four distinct coastlines on one landmass?
3. Can you name the one country that has exactly six distinct coastlines on one landmass?

Comment: I'm fine with people using computers, and in fact, you need some geography that is not common knowledge to solve this. As to your second question, I'm afraid I can't answer without a spoiler!

Comment: So why are countries on single islands like Australia, Madagascar, etc. not counted as 4 coastline countries?

Comment: Because they have one continuous coastline?

Comment: Coastline... so you mean border that matches water, not a coast line. Australia has a northern coast, a southern coast, etc.. and a ton inbetween.

Comment: I'm using the definition in the first sentence of the riddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Answers

*Can you name the four countries in the world that have exactly three distinct coastlines on one landmass?*

> Canada, Saudi Arabia, Malaysia, France

*Can you name the three countries in the world that have exactly four distinct coastlines on one landmass?*

> The United States of America, Morocco, Russia

*Can you name the one country that has exactly six distinct coastlines on one landmass?*

> Spain

---

### Explanations

One of the two countries with four distinct coastlines (by this definition) is

> The United States of America.

The four coastlines (on one landmass) are:

> Alaska, Point Roberts, the Pacific coast (Washington to California), the Atlantic coast (Maine to Texas).
>  If you count Great Salt Lake as fitting your definition of "major saltwater sea", you could even make a case for this being a 5-coastline country.

---

This makes the second 4-coastline country:

> Morocco

The four coasts are:

> 1. West of Ceuta
>  2. Between Ceuta and Peñón de Vélez de la Gomera
>  3. Between Peñón de Vélez de la Gomera and Melilla
>  4. East of Melilla
>  *(Melilla credit to [kaine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20829/tricoastal-and-quadricoastal-countries/20830?noredirect=1#comment65631_20830))*
>  *(Peñón de Vélez de la Gomera credit to [eudes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/20835/10399))*

---

The final 4-coastline country is:

> Russia

The coastlines are:

> 1. Black Sea
>  2. Pacific Ocean
>  3. Baltic Sea (Kaliningrad)
>  4. Baltic Sea (St Petersburg)
>  I don't include the occupied territory of the Crimean peninsula. That's still part of Ukraine, even if Russia has tanks rolling all over it.

---

The ***6***-coastline country:

> Spain

The coastlines here are:

> 1. Atlantic Ocean (north shore)
>  2. Mediterranean Sea (East of Gibraltar)
>  3. Strait of Gibraltar (West of Gibraltar)
>  4. The coastline of Ceuta across the Strait on Morocco's coast
>  5. The coastline of Melilla *(credit to [kaine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20829/tricoastal-and-quadricoastal-countries/20830?noredirect=1#comment65631_20830) on this 5<sup>th</sup> coast)* to the East of Ceuta on Morocco's coast
>  6. The coastline of Peñón de Vélez de la Gomera *(credit to [eudes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/20835/10399) on this 6<sup>th</sup> coast)* on Morocco's coast
>   .... **Those sneaky Spanish!!**

---

The four three-coastline countries are:

> 1. Canada — Pacific Ocean, Boundary Bay, Atlantic/Arctic Ocean
>  2. Saudi Arabia — Red Sea, Persian Gulf (x2) *(credit to [Bailey M](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/20832/10399))*
>  3. Malaysia — South China Sea (x3, split twice by Brunei) .. bonus+2 Malacca Strait split by Singapore *(credit to [kaine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/20833/10399))*
>  4. France — North shore, south shore (x2, split by Monte Carlo)

---

Previously, I had listed Germany as a three-coastline country, but I suspect that Szczecin Lagoon is counted as a continuous extension of the Baltic Sea.

Comment: Note: France because of Monaco

Comment: @kaine I just noticed that, too! :)

Comment: I can't tell what's going on with the borders on Cyprus... :(

Comment: How are the Strait and Mediterranean coasts broken up?  ...The coast of Mellila is 4 though. (which gives Morrocco 3)

Comment: They're broken by Gibraltar.

Comment: I did not realise that was not spanish... ok... 5 coastlines then

Comment: Very nice! Yes, I am not counting Eurasiafrica as a landmass. Also, I never knew about Peñón de Vélez de la Gomera, so you're right about Morocco with four. But one of your three-coast countries actually has four. Updating the question now, I'm confident you'll get it.

Comment: @Luke: I upped Canada's count, but wouldn't that push USA to 5 for NY's north coast on the St Lawrence (and Lake Ontario)?

Comment: Canada is not what I was thinking of. If I count rivers as breaking coastlines (even ones as wide as the St. Lawrence), that's a whole new can of worms. There's another country in your list that definitely has four.

Comment: @Luke You counted the Suez as breaking coastlines, though.

Comment: You are right. For posterity's sake, I'm going to give you the Suez (6 coastlines for Spain!) to stay consistent. Which gives us four with three, three with four, and one with six.

Comment: This is an awesome answer, thanks for playing along as I made the puzzle actually correct!

Comment: Nobody expects the Spanish... coastlines? Was hoping for a pun there.

Comment: @Ian `apart from islands` yep, I missed those three words. Carry on good sir.

Answer (score 3):

Some countries not yet mentioned (I assume that exclaves can be included, if on the same landmass):
2 coastlines:

> 1. Oman, because of Musandam Peninsula
>  2. Brunei – indeed, two parts!
>  3. Lithuania, on Baltic Sea "proper" and on Curonian Spit
>  4. Ukraine, if Crimea is considered in Russia (see below). Also, the region of Budjak is separated from the "mainland" Ukraine by the Dniester estuary, though of course connected through some bridges (see [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/@46.2959846,30.2600494,33604m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0)) – but this probably shouldn't count as separate coastline.

3 coastlines:

> Spain, because of Gibraltar, but:

6 coastlines

> Spain, if we can treat Eurasia+Africa as one landmass, because it includes a few territories in North Africa, bordering Morocco, of which Ceuta, Melilla and Peñón de Vélez de la Gomera are parts of land.

And finally, with possibly 8:

> Russia.
>  Depending on how we define a distinct coastline precisely, Russia may have even 8 of them (6, if excluding unlawfully annexed Crimea). I describe them below, according to maps I found, and let the reader decide on their own, which are right.
>  1. with the Pacific and Arctic Oceans, from Vladivostok up to Murmansk
>  2. with the Baltic Sea (Gulf of Finland), around St. Petersburg
>  3. (in the Kaliningrad Oblast) with the Baltic Sea (Curonian Lagoon), inside the lagoon
>  4. (KO cont.) with the Baltic Sea (incl. Vistula Lagoon), from the Lithuanian border on the Curonian Spit to the Polish border inside the Vistula Lagoon
>  5. (KO cont.) with the Baltic Sea (incl. Vistula Lagoon), on the Vistula Spit. However, the Strait of Baltiysk, which currently separates the spit from the mainland, is artificial, albeit old (1497)
>  6. with the Syvash lagoons of the Sea o Azov, from the Isthmus of Perekop to the de facto border with Ukraine on the Arabat Spit, just south of Strilkove village
>  7. with the Black Sea and the Sea of Azov, the remainder of the coastline of the Crimean Peninsula
>  The Crimean Peninsula is de facto administered by Russia. Hovewer, this administration isn't "recognised by most of the international community" (by en.wiki/Crimea), so 6 and 7 are not officialy in Russia.
>  8. with the Sea of Azov and the Black Sea, from Taganrog to Sochi.

Also, a comment, if I may (can't comment normally yet). It seems to me that

> Germany has only 2 coastlines, because Szczecin Lagoon is connected with the rest of Baltic Coast – you can walk along [Uznam Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uznam).

Comment: Which eudes is the real eudes? O.o

Comment: @Bailey M We're both the same (and the sane)! We've managed to merge since, though.

Answer (score 1):

Still a partial answer:

2 Coast lines:

> - Germany
>  - Spain
>  - North Korea
>  - Mexico
>  - Guatemala
>  - Hondoras
>  - Nicaragua
>  - Costa Rica
>  - Panama
>  - Columbia
>  - Argentina
>  - Turkey
>  - Egypt
>  - Isreal
>  - Senegal
>  - Croatia
>  - Thailand
>  - China (depending on how you view Hong Kong)
>  - United Arab Emirates

3 Coast lines:

> - Russia
>  - Saudi Arabia
>  - Canada
>  - Malaysia
>  - France

4 Coast lines:

> - United states

Comment: Canada actually has 3 (Pacific ocean, Boundary Bay, Atlantic and Arctic).

Comment: Malaysia is very odd.  It has 3 on one landmass and 2 on another.

Comment: With the Suez Canal joining the Red to the Mediterranean, does Egypt not just count as 1?

Comment: I think that is debatable.  At very least it is artifical and tiny.

Comment: Well, then I found the second four-coast country. ;)